# How would I make a discord bot that can point out a link?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to make a discord bot that will delete discord server invites, but I can't figure out how to make it so that the bot knows what the link is, this is what I've tried so far:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "https://discord.") #This along with the 'def gg' is trying to specify a discord invite
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Its working')

@client.command()
async def gg(ctx):
    #I need this to find out if it is a link

client.run('(Token)')
```

If you have a solution to this or something that would be more efficient I would love to read it.

Comment: Use the [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Client.wait_for) event to check for links, not this hacky way of using the command prefix with commands.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'm very new to discord.py and this helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Client.wait_for) event, you can easily find server invite links. Using the bot prefix in that way is not a good way of doing things. Also, be aware that discord will still embed an invite even if it's a hyperlink, so `discord.gg/invite_code` will still show the embed, even though discord won't mark it as a hyperlink.